# Android - scroll to a specific vieu with small device

Tags: android, scrollview, smooth-scrolling

I want to scroll to a specific inflated view in ScrollView but after the scroll the item is either more below or partially shown.

Here's my code :

```
page.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    page.computeScroll();
                    page.smoothScrollTo(0, myView.getBottom());
                    // ...
                }
            }, 200);
```

If you have an idea, or you need more explanations, please tell me.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you well. Are you trying to scroll to a specific item position into the list view?

Comment: No, to a specific inflated item (LinearLayout) in scrollview

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. Why are you using `myView.getBottom()` instead of `myView.getY()`?

Comment: I tried both but same result :/
In top of inflated element i have an other element ("not" inflated), maybe it's that which shift the view position ?

Comment: I do not know, it is hard to say. You should edit and post this and any other relevant code to your question.

Comment: Okay i resolve that "bug", i juste did
page.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) view.getY() + header.getHeight());
thanks for your answer